# How to add javadocs in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, javadoc

I'm trying to add Javadocs to Netbeans 7.2. But I can't, because it errored with `No documentation found` on Javadoc intex search tab; clicking <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

I tried the following suggestion:

```
tools > java flatforms > javadoc(tab) > add ZIP/folder
```

and finally click close Java flatform manager. My docs name is "jdk-7u6-apidocs.zip".

Answer (score 3):

Goto `Tools --> Java Platforms`
Here you can see your java platforms added. Select one and on right side goto `Javadoc` tab and select your `zip file`

Comment: There is only JDK 1.7 (default). I did it. but not.